# connect Java to Active Directory

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, md5, jndi

I try to connect to Active Directory with my Java code, but I get this error message :

```
Début du test Active Directory
Search error: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C:
LdapErr: DSID-0C0904DC, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
```

I use JNDI,the DIGEST-MD5 authentication method and no encryption method
this is my code:

```
public class TestAD {
    static DirContext ldapContext;
    public static void main (String[] args) throws NamingException
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Début du test Active Directory");

            Hashtable<String, String> ldapEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>(11);
            ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  "ldap://societe.fr:389");
            ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "DIGEST-MD5");
            ldapEnv.put("java.naming.security.sasl.realm","myRealm");
            ldapEnv.put("javax.security.sasl.qop", "auth");
            ldapEnv.put("javax.security.sasl.strength","high");
            ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "dn:cn=administrateur,ou=users,o=societe.fr");
            ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"myPassword");

            ldapContext = new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv);

            // Create the search controls         
            SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();

            // Specify the attributes to return
            String returnedAtts[]={"sn","givenName", "samAccountName"};
            searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);

            // Specify the search scope
            searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

            // specify the LDAP search filter
            String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user))";

            // Specify the Base for the search
            String searchBase = "dc=societe,dc=fr";
            // initialize counter to total the results
            int totalResults = 0;

            // Search for objects using the filter
            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ldapContext.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);

            // Loop through the search results
            while (answer.hasMoreElements())
            {
                SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next();

                totalResults++;

                System.out.println(">>>" + sr.getName());
                Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
                System.out.println(">>>>>>" + attrs.get("samAccountName"));
            }

            System.out.println("Total results: " + totalResults);
            ldapContext.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(" Search error: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S.:I can connect to my Active Directory with the same parameter with Apache Directory Studio

Comment: I'm not Java-ist, but aren't you missing a letter in Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION? Perhaps it should be "DIGEST-MD5"? Also, I do not see anywhere that you instruct the program to use ldap v3. While this might not be related to your problem, I strongly recommend using v3 protocol.

Comment: sorry in fact it's "DIGEST-MD5",i will fix my post,thank's

Comment: @ShadowWalker The "ldap:" scheme instructs the program to use ldapv3.

Comment: Then it looks like an authentication problem ( wrong password or wrong authentication type or something similar... The error 52e is roughly explained [here](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=LDAP_Error_Codes).

Comment: no,i can connect to active directory with the same IDs in Apache Directory Studio

Comment: But was ADS configured to use SASL/DIGEST-MD5? Are you sure those are the right settings?

Comment: @EJP:yes,like i said,i can connect to active directory with Apache Directory Studio using the same parameter

Comment: You didn't say that at all. You said 'with the same IDs'. It's not the same thing, and it doesn't answer my question. Specifically you didn't say anything about using SASL and DIGEST-MD5 with ADS. Is that what you specified?

Comment: @EJP:i specified that just after my error msg

Comment: Have you installed  Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) ? (For "javax.security.sasl.strength","high")

Comment: @jeemster: yes, I just installed it but I have the same problem

Comment: i found the solution of my problem,it was in this line: ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "dn:cn=administrateur,ou=users,o=societe.fr"); it suffices to write just the user nam like this : ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "administrateur")

Comment: bro can you help me, I need to understand how you are doing it